# Compiler+Library: how to set library folder, but don't compile it?

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler

I've got an application that uses Openlayers library. Openlayers uses Closure Library.

I want to compile everything (application, Openlayers and Closure Library) into a single whole_application.js file.

The problem is that Closure Compiler runs on all sources, putting the unused functions into my whole_application.js file, such as goog.ui.

My application is written in ES5, around a simple goog.require/goog.provide. (I also want to port it to ES6)

I want to set something like root.js - root of the dependencies tree - a file with all goog.require's, where I can write

```
goog.provide('myApplication');

goog.require('ol.source.Vector'); // openlayers module
goog.require('myApplication.someModule');
```

and be happy.
Is there any way to do it?

Or, can I set folder with my source code to compile everything inside it, and a folder with dependencies (such as openlayers/closure library) to just search the needed dependencies there?

Or, maybe, there are some other solutions?

Compilation/Deployment is performed with gulp / google-closure-compiler.
Here's the script:

```
dirs.deploy = 'folder/with/my/sources'

var closureLibraryPath = './node_modules/google-closure-library/'

var closureLibraryExcludes = [
  "!**/*_test.js",
  "!**/*_perf.js",
  "!**/*tester.js",
  "!**/*promise/testsuiteadapter.js",
  "!**/*osapi/osapi.js",
  "!**/*svgpan/svgpan.js",
  "!**/*alltests.js",
  "!**/*node_modules**.js",
  "!**/*protractor_spec.js",
  "!**/*protractor.conf.js",
  "!**/*browser_capabilities.js",
  "!./doc/**.js"
];

gulp.task('deps-deploy', ['copy'], function (cb) {
  var exec = require('child_process').exec;
  exec(`
    cd ` + dirs.deploy + `/js &&
    chmod 644 deps.js &&
    "./` + closureLibraryPath + 'closure/bin/build/depswriter.py" ui.js --root_with_prefix="assets assets" > deps.js');
});


gulp.task('process-broadcast-assets', ['deps-deploy', 'copy', 'clean'], function() {
      var compilerOptions = {
    "compilation_level": "SIMPLE",
    "language_in": "ECMASCRIPT6",
    "language_out": "ECMASCRIPT5",
    "source_map_format": "V3",
    "warning_level": "QUIET",
    "formatting": "PRETTY_PRINT",
    "js_output_file": "whole_application.js",
    "output_wrapper": "%output%"
  };
  var paths = [].concat(dirs.deploy + '/js/assets/**/*.js', closureLibraryPath + 'closure/goog/**/*.js', closureLibraryPath + 'third_party/**/*.js' );
      paths = paths.concat(closureLibraryExcludes);
      return gulp.src(paths)
      .pipe(chmod(644))
      .pipe(closureCompiler(compilerOptions))
      .on('warning', onWarning)
      .on('error', onError)
      .pipe(gulp.dest(dirs.deploy + '/js'));
});
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The problem is that Closure Compiler runs on all sources, putting the unused functions into my whole_application.js file, such as goog.ui.

You need to use the [dependency management](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/Managing-Dependencies) flags. Based off your example, you probably want `STRICT` mode and an entry point of `goog:myApplication`. The compiler will drop any file that isn't required by your app.